# Why does ace editor use dollar sign for some object properties?

Tags: javascript, naming-conventions, ace-editor

I see that it is common to use the dollar sign when you have a variable that stores a jQuery object or when your code is "automatically generated" (whatever that might mean). However, the javascript [ace editor](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace) uses it for something else, see for instance [here](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/9200b313b9923abc28c40cf597571106328de4a0/lib/ace/anchor.js#L73). What could the reasoning be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ace uses `$` prefix for denoting internal methods and and properties.